# Merging exists and not exists into one query - oracle magic

Tags: oracle, plsql

In a WHERE part of query we have

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable st
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM Tab t1 WHERE t1.A = st.A OR t1.B = st.A)
OR EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM Tab t2 WHERE (t2.A = st.A OR t2.B = st.A) AND t2.C IS NULL)
```

Seems like a good candidate for merging...
But I'm staring on that for an hour without any idea.

Would you have some thoughts?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure that this is Oracle? SQL Server uses @ for parameters

Comment: Sure, that is just my pseudo-code, you will need aliases for both queries as well etc

Comment: If you had used colons instead of @ signs, this would be real Oracle code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct st.* 
FROM SomeTable st 
     left outer join Tab t
     on st.a in (t.a,t.b)
WHERE t.c is null
```

Sometimes the simplest answer is to use a join rather than an exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tab WHERE (Tab.A = @Id OR Tab.B = @ID)
            AND (Tab.C is null OR Tab.C != @Var))
```

Comment: Well in fact my @var = NULL ;-)
And the second part is saying 
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tab WHERE (Tab.A = @Id OR Tab.B = @ID) AND Tab.C IS NULL)

That is why I'm thinking about:
SELECT 1 FROM spb_trade_match m3 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(Tab.A = @Id AND Tab.C IS NOT NULL) OR 
(Tab.B = @Id AND Tab.C IS NOT NULL)

Comment: I think I caused some issues with my syntax. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable st
WHERE 
0 = (SELECT SUM (NVL(t1.C,0) FROM Tab t1 WHERE t1.A = st.A OR t1.B = st.A)
```

What do you think?
Of course that will work only for case where 'C' is expected to be NULL.
If we are expecting some value, I think that the check

```
@SomeValue IN (SELECT t1.C FROM Tab t1 WHERE t1.A = st.A OR t1.B = st.A)
```

Will do?

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* as though you're trying to return all SomeTable values where there's no corresponding value on Tab where C is not null - in which case, the following should work:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable st
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM Tab t1 WHERE (t1.A = st.A OR t1.B = st.A) AND t2.C IS NOT NULL)
```

However, that's not *exactly* what your existing query does - in your query, if there are two corresponding records on Tab, where one record has a non-null value for C and the other is null, your query will return a corresponding row, but my query won't.

Comment: That is why I come up with the SUM approach on NVL (on the assumption that we can SUM C column), need to sort out the case when that is not possible. DECODE will be probably handy...

Comment: So - do you know whether you can have null and non-null values of C in Tab for the same SomeTable record? Or is this an academic exercise?